# Select-Object calculated property from variable

Tags: powershell, calculated-field, select-object

I'm aware that we can specify a comma-separated string[] of properties in a variable to the Select-Object `-Property` parameter. However, I'm trying to include calculated properties in that variable. Tried adding it by enclosing them in single-quotes / double-quotes like,

1. `$selectProps = "distinguishedname",
   '@{n="lastlogontimestamp";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastlogontimestamp).ToString()}}'`

   and
2. `` $selectProps = "distinguishedname","@{n=`"lastlogontimestamp`";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime(`$_.lastlogontimestamp).ToString()}}" ``

   but to no avail. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a string in a variable you should wrap that in quotes. But as the hashtable is not a string you don't have to put it in quotes.  ;-)

```
$selectProps = @(
    'distinguishedname',
    @{ Name = 'lastlogontimestamp'; Expression = { [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastlogontimestamp).ToString() } }
)
```

It would work without wrapping the array in `@()` ... that's just a visual support to make it easier readable.

If you want to add more than one array with calculated properties to your `Select-Object` command you can add them together like this for example:

```
Select-Object -Property ($SelectProps + $SelectProps2)
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, That makes sense :) ... I'd like to just rephrase my question. I'm wanting to add the calculated property hashtable to an existing `$selectProps` array of strings. How would I do that ?